# German keyboard mapping in normal mode not working

Tags: vim

I mapped the german umlauts on my keyboard to often used keys:

```
imap ö {
imap Ö }
imap ä [
imap Ä ]
```

and for normal mode as well:

```
nmap ö {
nmap Ö }
nmap ä [
nmap Ä ]
```

In insert mode, this works just fine, but when it comes to normal mode, I can't get this working. Pressing fö does find ö, not {. Ok, I could map fö to f{, but that shouldn't be the way to do this, should it? Why doesn't ö expand to { in normal mode?

-- Update: Using a keymap-file mostly works for me now, I actually can get fö => f{ working. But on the other hand, äö => [{ or using ö to jump paragraphs does not work. Using the tip from the comments (map and map!) doesn't work for me either (fö and äö not working). Strangely, using map and map! I'm actually able to jump up paragraphs using ö, but that's it. I can't figure out what is going on here, does anyone know how I can get the complete thing working? (When an action is not working, I get a small symbol at the right top of vim, looks like a light bulb or something. Maybe that helps?)

Comment: Use `map` and `map!` to map in all modes. You missed operator pending mode.

Answer (score 1):

Although it did not work for me personally, in the comments, kopischke says that using `map!` works for him, just as FDinoff commented.

You need to make a keymap for this to work. (See `:h mapmode-l` and `h: 45.5`)

To do this, create a directory called `keymap` inside your `.vim` folder. You should have `~/.vim/keymap`. Go there and make a file called `german.vim` (or whatever you like).

There you can remap keys completely:

```
let b:keymap_name = "ger"
loadkeymap

ö {
Ö }
ä [
Ä ]
```

Then, in you `.vimrc` file, place this line:

```
set keymap=german
```

This will remap those keys completely, so you can remove your other mappings (like the `imap`)

Comment: This is shooting cannons at sparrows, as the German sayings goes. See @FDinoff’s comment for an understanding of the original issue,

Comment: Although it using `map!` should fix his issue, it did not work for me. Did you try doing `:map! ö {` in vim? Because when I did it it didn't work.

Comment: I did, worked fine for me in MacVim with the Apple BT KB, tho I ended up using something entirely different for other reasons. I’m not saying there aren’t valid reasons to go the full keymap route, but they would need to be outlined along the alternatives in your answer. Also, aren't keymap mappings only supposed to work in insert, search and command line mode?